# What happens when I deactivate a publishing feature?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing

I am kind of a newbie to sharepoint...
I have a site where the publishing feature was turned on.  There are no file under Pages All web pages are under Site Pages.  I have files under documents and the image folders.
If I deactivate the publishing feature will anything break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will break but it means you can do certain things like publishing functionality at the site collection level, and the SharePoint Server Publishing feature provides publishing functionality at the site level.

This will give you a good overview...

[Publishing features overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff628963%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you enable the SharePoint Server Publishing feature and attempt to restore a backed up site with this feature having been turned on once (even if you disable it before a backup), there will be issues with restoring that site.